# Geo location in adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I was trying to create a campaign using the Adwords API and define the location of it.

The problem is that when I follow the example given [here][1] https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/location-targeting

CampaignCriterionService don't have a mutate method, I was spending sometime on it, I am asking if someone has seen this problem before and if so how did he solved it?

For me the instructions in their site are a little confusing....

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the following code to create the campaignCriterionService.As i could see CampaignCriterionServiceInterface has mutate method.

```
CampaignCriterionServiceInterface campaignCriterionService =
        adWordsServices.get(session, CampaignCriterionServiceInterface.class);
```

Comment: I used the wrong class, CampaignCriterionService only. Since in their example the name of the variable was campaignCriterionService so I used that one by mistake, they don't show the declaration of it so.... Anyhow thank you @Thakur Vishal it did help.